# Installing Tensorflow Windows "Nightly Build" using PIP

Tags: jenkins, tensorflow, nightly-build

I need to install a Tensorflow nightly build since the latest stable release has a critical issue that doesn't allow me to work that seems fixed in nightly.
I want to avoid to try to compile myself Tensorflow from source and I have found a [guide](https://tillahoffmann.github.io/2016/11/03/Installing-tensorflow-nightly-builds.html) about installing Nightly build using PIP
Eg this command

```
pip install http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-matrix-cpu/TF_BUILD_IS_OPT=OPT,TF_BUILD_IS_PIP=PIP,TF_BUILD_PYTHON_VERSION=PYTHON3,label=mac-slave/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/pip_test/whl/tensorflow-0.11.0rc1-py3-none-any.whl
```

was for tensorflow 0.11 nightly build for Mac

Looking at [this link](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/) and link for [windows nightly build](https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/DEVICE=cpu,OS=windows/): 
I have tried to adjust the command to install tensorflow 1.0.1 for windows nightly in this way:

```
pip install http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/TF_BUILD_CONTAINER_TYPE=CPU,TF_BUILD_IS_OPT=OPT,TF_BUILD_IS_PIP=PIP,TF_BUILD_PYTHON_VERSION=PYTHON3 /lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/pip_test/whl/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

with no success

Could someone help me?

Comment: You should https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac

Comment: @AjaySingh I don't need to install tensorflow on MAC, I need to install the latest nightly build for Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the latest Nightly Build from Jenkins (https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/DEVICE=cpu,OS=windows/121/)

I put the file in C:\tensorflow\tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

And was able to successfully install with

> pip3 install C:\tensorflow\tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_a
>   md64.whl